# Symfony2 Doctrine2 MS SQL Server connection on WHM/CPanel

Tags: sql-server-2008, doctrine-orm, symfony

SEE UPDATE BELOW:

I'm using Symfony2/Doctrine2 on CPanel and I need to make a connection to a MS SQL Server database. I keep getting an error saying

> could not find driver

I've tried to install FreeTDS on WHM/CPanel following these instructions:

http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/definitive-freetds-installation-instuctions-88561.html

I also added an additional option to the PHP compilation (all_php5) so it looks like this:

--with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds --with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/freetds

I then also added an entry to my php.ini file (/usr/local/lib/php.ini) that says:

> extension= "mssql.so"

I rebuilt Apache/PHP after making all these changes but I still get the error saying the driver cannot be found. Anybody have this setup and know what I'm missing?

UPDATE:

So, instead of compiling FreeTDS, I found some packages through yum which I installed. I did, however, compile .so files for both mssql.so and pdo_dblib.so. They are now both referenced in my php.ini that I know is getting loaded. I can successfully use the mssql_* functions but PDO is still not working for me. I still get the the "could not find driver" error. I no longer have an all_php5 file since I don't think I need it anymore since I just compiled the .so files. Is this correct? What else can I do to get PDO working? Here is a screenshot of my phpinfo() page:

[image: PDO]

Comment: I can't actually find the mssql.so file on my system. It's not in the PHP extensions folder where I would expect it to be. I read another article that said it might be named phph_mssql.so but I can't find that either.

Comment: This gives some additional hints but it's still not working for me: http://forums.cpanel.net/f354/adding-mssql-support-php-66644.html#post365833. I now noticed that I'm getting an error when PHP gets recompiled: 

configure: error: Directory /usr/local/freetds --with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/freetds is not a FreeTDS installation directory

The FreeTDS site says that touching two files will cause this to go away but it's definitely not working for me.

http://www.freetds.org/news.html

Comment: Another resource I'm looking into: http://howtogetitworking.com/2008/02/26/how-to-install-mssql-extension-for-php-on-unix/

Comment: I got mssql.so installed correctly. It shows up in phpinfo() and I can even run php code using the mssql_* functions and they return data to me correctly. Looks like I need the missing PDO piece now?

Comment: Did you find a way ? I'm in the exact same situation. I found this [bundle](https://github.com/trooney/PDODblibBundle) (Apparently bringing the missing part) but I don't know how to install it